How to Enforce Correct Method Chaining Style in PHP?
I'm looking to enforce a specific method chaining style in PHP, particularly to differentiate between what I consider the 'wrong' and 'good' styles. Is there a tool or method that can help check and enforce the preferred formatting?
Wrong example:
$queryBuilderMock->expects(self::once())
        ->method('getQuery')
        ->willReturn($queryMock);

Preferred example:
$queryBuilderMock
        ->expects(self::once())
        ->method('getQuery')
        ->willReturn($queryMock);

I'm interested in whether tools like PHP CS Fixer or PHP_CodeSniffer can be configured to enforce this style, or if there are other methods or tools recommended for this purpose.

It took a little bit to see what you were talking about (not enough coffee on my side). Just to be clear, you want to enforce that when more than one -> is used, they should always be on dedicated lines and indented, with the ; appearing on the terminal line, right? PSR-12 appears to disallow this, but PER 2.0 explicitly says to do exactly that. I don't have specific knowledge in how to accomplish this, unfortunately, but hopefully it helps you find a solution.

@ChrisHaas Yes, exactly, there is no official PHP cs fixer rule for this one, so maybe there is some existing custom rule as a suggestion or way how to check those on the CI pipeline.
BTW sorry for the late response. :)
